# How do you put jsfiddle on your html

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may be the thickest question ever! But how do I get this to work on my html?

HTML

```html
<div class="test2"></div>

<div class="test"></div>

<div class="test3"></div>
```

CSS

```css
.test2 {margin-top: 250px;
       position:absolute;
       left: -100px;
       width:100px;
       height:100px;
       background: aqua;
}

.test {margin-top: 500px;
       position:absolute;
       right: -100px;
       width:100px;
       height:100px;
       background: aqua;
}

.test3 {margin-top: 1000px;
       position:absolute;
       right: 100px;
       width:100px;
       height:100px;
       background: aqua;
} ​​
```

JS

```js
var $test2 = $(".test2");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $test2.stop().animate({
            left: "200px"
        }, 200);
    }
});    

var $test = $(".test");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $test.stop().animate({
            right: "200px"
        }, 400);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maxmitch/UgEu6/ (complete sample)

Comment: Get what to work?  When I scroll, the DIVs animate and move into the page.  You need to rewrite your question so that it will be clearer on what you are actually asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "get this to work on my html?"

Comment: Is there any reason you're putting the url in apostrophes? Are you trying to circumvent the filter that asks you NOT to simply post jsfiddles?

Comment: Also, please don't post duplicates of your *own* questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421538/how-to-get-multiple-divs-to-slide-in-on-different-scroll-heights-from-right-or-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to get a one page working version of a jsFiddle is to use their "Share full screen result" link, which for your example is jsfiddle.net/maxmitch/UgEu6/embedded/result/.

Then all you need to do is right click on the main frame and copy the source code. Note that if you're using jsFiddle's "normalize css" option that you'll have to adjust the path to the CSS files you see.

Answer (score 0):

"On your html?" I... it doesn't work "on your html".  You have 3 files there. A javascript file, a CSS file, and your HTML file.

On the left, you'll see it uses the jQuery 1.7.2 library in the `onDomReady` event, which if I remember is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code to execute
})
```

You'll need to create 3 separate files for each.  You'll need to know how to get the CSS and Javascript files into your HTML document.  Google it if you don't know.

Comment: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="delete.css" type="text/css">
<script src="slide in.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="test2"></div>

<div class="test"></div>

<div class="test3"></div>

<div class="test4"></div>'

Comment: I have done this but it still doesn't work!
Thanks for your help so far